# Get current row along with the next and previous records

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is getting the current record, along with the next and previous records. But I need to do it so that it doens't have to be the next consecutive ID.

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username,
    (select user_id -1 as user_id from users where user_id = u.user_id) as prev_id,
    (select user_id +1 as user_id from users where user_id = u.user_id) as next_id
from users u
where u.user_id = 3
```

This returning what I need, but if user_id 4 doesn't exist, how would I get the next record?

Also, is this the fastest way to do this?

Thanks for the help?

Comment: it is several layers of complexity lower to do this in the application using the data than the query itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use limit to get the next and previous id. For example:

```
  select
          u.user_id,
          u.first_name,
          u.last_name,
          u.username,
          (select user_id as user_id 
           from users 
           where user_id <u.user_id 
           order by user_id desc
           limit 1 ) as prev_id,
           (select user_id as user_id 
           from users 
           where user_id >u.user_id 
           order by user_id asc
           limit 1 ) as next_id
        from users u
        where u.user_id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple of joins and aggregate functions:-

```
select u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username,
    MAX(u_prev.user_id) AS prev_id,
    MIN(u_next.user_id) AS next_id
from users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u_prev ON u.user_id > u_prev.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u_next ON u.user_id < u_next.user_id
where u.user_id = 3
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE id >= (
 SELECT id 
 FROM `user` 
 WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM `user` WHERE firstname = 'abc')
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Hope this will help you.